# log request method on routing

Tags: node.js, express

For my NodeJs project I use the Express router. I created a **router.js**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use('/', require('./routes/home.js'));
    app.use('/contact', require('./routes/contact.js'));
    app.use('/imprint', require('./routes/imprint.js'));
};
```

and in my **app.js** I require this file `require('./server/router.js')(app);`. When calling a route, for example `/contact` I require the **contact.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact', { // render contact.hbs
        title: 'Contact' // pass in some template variables
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Within `router.get` I can use `console.log(req.method)` to log the HTTP method. Currently I would have to log this in all router files. Is it possible to have the code at one place like

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    console.log(req.method); // Log the request method for all routes

    app.use('/', require('./routes/home.js'));
    app.use('/contact', require('./routes/contact.js'));
    app.use('/imprint', require('./routes/imprint.js'));
};
```

Please provide a solution without installing middleware. I know there are many loggers out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to avoid installing middleware and use `console.log` you can change your code as follows:

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
       console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
       console.log('Time:', Date.now());
       next();
    })

    app.use('/', require('./routes/home.js'));
    app.use('/contact', require('./routes/contact.js'));
    app.use('/imprint', require('./routes/imprint.js'));
};
```

If you don't specify a route but have the `next` callback in, then it will execute your logging code first then the matching routing if there is one. You can find more details in the using middleware section of the [ExpressJS API documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).